# SQL Server table transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table something like this:

| due_date | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | FALSE |
| 2019-01-01 | FALSE |
| 2018-12-01 | FALSE |
| 2018-11-01 | TRUE |
| 2018-10-01 | FALSE |
| 2018-09-01 | FALSE |
| 2018-08-01 | TRUE |

And the output table is:

| due_date | flag | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | FALSE | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 | FALSE | 1 |
| 2018-12-01 | FALSE | 1 |
| 2018-11-01 | TRUE | 2 |
| 2018-10-01 | FALSE | 3 |
| 2018-09-01 | FALSE | 3 |
| 2018-08-01 | TRUE | 4 |

I have tried using the lag function, using this query

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    LAG(flag, 1, 'FALSE') OVER (ORDER BY due_date DESC) AS lag_flag
FROM 
    tableName
```

The result will become like this:

| due_date | flag | lag_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2019-01-01 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2018-12-01 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2018-11-01 | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2018-10-01 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2018-09-01 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2018-08-01 | TRUE | FALSE |

And right now I'm stuck at this step. Anyone can suggest to me the next steps? (please also tell me the query)

Note: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag start of a group with 1 and compute the rolling total of the starting flag.

```
select due_date, flag, sum(f) OVER (ORDER BY due_date desc) x
from(
  select due_date, flag, 
     case when LAG(flag, 1, 'unknown') OVER (ORDER BY due_date desc) = flag then 0 else 1 end f
  from tbl
) t
ORDER BY due_date desc
```